# Catch unhandled exceptions on a form (not the entire application)

Tags: c#, exception

Is there any way to catch any unhandled exceptions on a form. I don't want to wrap hundreds of methods in hundreds of forms in a try catch block.

I do have a base form which each form inherits from.

Is there any way to catch any unhandled exceptions?

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific. Cannot you write the try-catch in Form_Load of the desired form.

Comment: take a look at here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx

Comment: Have a look at the following thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: see this link.Its help you.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911257/asp-net-c-sharp-catch-all-exceptions-in-a-class]

Comment: It already works this way, there's a default handler for Application.ThreadException that displays a dialog to tell the user about the problem.  You can replace it by subscribing your own event handler.

Comment: Handle locally, not at some intermediate level. What should a catch all catch?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do it. 
You can do only something like that:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
try
{
    form.ShowDialog();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Or you can use pattern Proxy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and create a class wrapper for a form that will have method ShowDialog and will have exception handling in it.

```
public class FormProxy<TForm> 
                      where TForm : Form
{
    private TForm _form;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I want to catch any exceptions that happen on a form so that I can log the details of the object that was on the form that caused the error